# Can I start the Activity without show it's layout on android screen?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-activity

my activity : A-->B-->C

when I start activity B, i want on android screen show the C layout not B layout,
can I do that?

thanks

Comment: Your question makes no sense. If you want Activity B to have the layout of Activity C then just start Activity C and forget about Activity B. What is the point of having a layout for B if you're never going to use it?

Answer (score 0):

if you specify in the B Activity in the onCreate method:

```
this.setContentView(clayout);
```

you get the C layout in the B activity.

Comment: Note that the .xml does not appear in the R... But the answer is good ;)

Comment: right...sorry didn't check. My memory makes mistakes; too much Google :P

Comment: Thax Perroloco,,
little correction about my question,

i think i mean is not layout but blank screen,,,

my activity
A-->B-->C,,
A start B, then B start C -->one execution,, 

when i start B the blank screen/without layout from B is appear(for a while) then show C...

can i start B without show the blank screen? it cause when i on C and i click back button, the blankscreen from B is appear

Comment: @panji: Why do you need to start Activity B in order to start Activity C? An Activity is designed to display a UI - what you're describing is an Activity which doesn't have a UI but is simply meant to start another Activity...that's not how Activities in Android are meant to work.

Comment: @MisterSquonk Oh,  i think activity is same with usual class in java.

Comment: @MisterSquonk I totally agree with you

Comment: @panji you can create normal java classes, and even start Activities from a class.

Comment: @panji: **"Oh, i think activity is same with usual class in java."** - No, an Activity is a 'special' class and is only meant to show a UI. If you want to start Activity C from Activity A then don't use an an Activity to do it - just have Activity A do whatever it needs to do then have it start Activity C directly.

Answer (score 0):

Use shared preference attach a value when activity starts check while reloading if it contains that variable skip and load that activity else start with Activity A